# Conversion between knitr and sweave

Tags: rstudio, knitr, sweave

This might have been asked before, but until now I couldn't find a really helpful answer for me.

I am using `R Studio` with `knitr` and a colleague of mine who I need to cooperate with uses the sweave format. Is there a good way to convert a script back and forth between these two?

I have already found **"Sweave2knitr"** and hoped this would have an `.rmd` as output with all chunks changed (`<<>>` to `{}` etc.) but this is not the case. My main problem is that I would also need the option to convert from `.rmd` back to `.rnw` so that my colleague can also re-edit my work-over.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To process the code chunks and convert the .Rnw file to .tex, you use the `knit()` function in the knitr package rather than Sweave().

```
R -e 'library(knitr);knit("my_file.Rnw")'
```

**Sweave2knitr()** is for converting old Sweave-based .Rnw files to the knitr syntax.

In Program defaults change :
Weave Rnw files using Sweave or knitr
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply - I'm sorry as I am quite new to the whole R and Knitr field and might just not understand you in the right way.I don't want to just knit the .Rnw file and I've never used Sweave(). - By the way, I think my colleague really uses Sweave-based files.

Answer (score 0):

The `Rnw` format is really LaTeX with some modifications, whereas the `Rmd` format is Markdown with some modifications.  There are two main flavours of `Rnw`, the one used by `Sweave` being the original, and the one used by `knitr` being a modification of it, but they are very similar.

It's not hard to change `Sweave` flavoured `Rnw` to `knitr` flavoured `Rnw` (that's what `Sweave2knitr` does), but changing either one to `Rmd` would require extensive changes, and probably isn't feasible:  certainly I'd expect a lot of manual work after the change.

So for your joint work with a co-author, I would recommend that you settle on a single format, and just use that.  I would choose `Rmd` for this:  it's much easier for your co-author to learn Markdown than for you to learn LaTeX.  (If you already know LaTeX, that might push the choice the other way.)